# Simulated PCRF Seagull script to send AAA only for final AAR

Tags: sip, diameter-protocol

I am modifying basic diameter scenario server script(PCRF) in such way that If I receive first AAR should not send AAA, I need to send AAA only if I receive Final AAR. please any one give me a hint or a script which will be great useful to me to continue with my scripting.

scenario

`UE                    AF          Egress Peer
  |                    |               |
  |---------INVITE---->|               |
  |          (offer)   |               |
  |                    |               |
  |<----100 Trying-----|               | 
  |   PCRF             |               |
  |     |              |               |
  |     |<---AAR-------|               |
  |     |              |               |
  |     |Should not    |               |
  |     |   send AAA   |               |
  |     |              |               |
  |                    |----INVITE---->|
  |                    |    (offer)    |
  |                    |               |
  |      |             |               |
  |                    |<----18x-------|
  |      |             |    (answer)   |
  |      |<-----AAR----|               |
  |      |----AAA----->|               |`

How to simulate PCRF for this behavior using seagull?

Comment: Please anyone one help mw with this....

Answer (score 1):

In general (assuming you know to run seagull and build a scenario)
You need to build a scenario that waits for 2 messages and only answers to the second one, something like this:

```
<traffic>
<receive channel="channel-1">
<command name="AAR">
AVPs....
</receive>

<traffic>
<receive channel="channel-1">
<command name="AAR">
AVPs....
</receive>

<send channel="channel-1">
<command name="AAA">
AVPs....
</send>
```

Good Luck